# Using mysql slow queries log with PHP

Tags: mysql

I enabled logging slow queries and set the minimum time to 0.  I know that the logging is enabled because the startup of mysqld is being logged.  But, when I access my website's php pages using my browser and cause queries to run, no queries are being logged.

Is there something special I need to do to make this work with php?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine setting it to 0 disables it. You should be using the [binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html) if you want to catch every single query going through MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MySQL is this? 0 only became a valid value for `long_query_time` in 5.1.21.